# Can I change a title with AngularJS to a different value based on the value of a service parameter?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
        <div id="logo"
             ng-show="uss.roleId == 1"      
             title="{{$state.current}}">
            <a ng-click="$state.transitionTo('home')" style="cursor: pointer;">abc</a>
        </div>

        <div id="logo"
             ng-show="uss.roleId != 1"      
             title="ABC">
            <a ng-click="$state.transitionTo('home')" style="cursor: pointer;">abc</a>
        </div>
```

Is there some way that I can avoid using two versions of this for a person with a roleId of 1 and a person who has a roleId that is not equal to 1?

Comment: So basically you want to update the title on the basis of roleId? e.g when roleId is 1, title is "Something" and when roleId !=1 title is "Something else"?

Comment: Correct. I want the admin with roleId of 1 to see a different title to other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, use a ternary operator directly in your html to do that:

```
        <div id="logo" 
             title="{{ (uss.roleId === 1) ? $state.current : "ABC" }}">
            <a ng-click="$state.transitionTo('home')" style="cursor: pointer;">abc</a>
        </div>
```

This ternary only works for angular 1.1.5+ though. If your Angular version is older, use the old ternary syntax:

(condition) && (answer if true) || (answer if false)

```
        <div id="logo" 
             title="{{ (uss.roleId === 1) && $state.current || "ABC" }}">
            <a ng-click="$state.transitionTo('home')" style="cursor: pointer;">abc</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: VERY GOOD !  Thanks so much.  I am using an older version of AngularJS but it's time to upgrade and I will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the text you want to display in a scope variable

```
$scope.displayText = ($scope.uss.roleId === 1) ? $state.current : "ABC";
```

and in the html

```
<div id="logo"
    title="{{displayText}}">
    <a ng-click="$state.transitionTo('home')" style="cursor: pointer;">abc</a>
</div>
```

The other option is to use a function that returns the string you want to display. This can be handy once the condition becomes more complex. When using the function keep in mind that it will be evaluated often so could have performance implications.

```
$scope.getDisplayText = function () { 
    return ($scope.uss.roleId === 1) ? $state.current : "ABC";
};
```

and

```
<div id="logo"
    title="{{getDisplayText()}}">
    <a ng-click="$state.transitionTo('home')" style="cursor: pointer;">abc</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could just code that into the HTML of the page? Could I put that equation with the ? into the {{ }} ? That would be very good if I could do that ?